# replace default new page with visual force page

Tags: visualforce

We want a custom visual force page to be used when a user clicks new on a custom object. I can seem to easily replace the edit page but how do I get salesforce to use a visual force page for the default new record button

Comment: Isn't it nearly identical to overriding the edit button? Simply going to the `Buttons, Actions, and Links` section of your custom object, finding the `New` button, and clicking `edit` should allow you to choose a Visualforce page to use as an override.

Comment: Yeah dumb question. I'm going to delete it but thanks a lot Derek. I was making this a little more complicated than it needed to be

Comment: I wouldn't delete this unless you can find a duplicate question (I did a cursory search, but didn't find anything). Yes, it's a simple question, and probably covered by existing documentation, but getting the information exposed in more places makes it easier for others to solve their problems as well. I'll start writing an answer based on my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the <kbd>New</kbd> button for a custom object ends up being a pretty similar process to overriding the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button.

There are two pieces of documentation that have relevant information.

- [Override Standard Buttons and Tab Home Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=links_customize_override.htm)
- [Considerations for Overriding Standard Buttons](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=links_override_considerations.htm&language=en_US)

The gist of the first link is that to override the `New` button, you go to

> Setup => Create => Objects => Click the name of your Custom Object

From there, click the `Buttons, Links, and Actions` link at the top of the page (or just scroll down). Then, click the `Edit` action link next to `New`. This brings you to the page where you can override the button with a Visualforce page.

Don't forget that you can only use Visualforce pages that use the standard controller for your custom object. If your object is `MyCustomObject__c`, you'd need to have the following in your Visualforce page *at a minimum*

```
<apex:page standardController="MyCustomObject__c">
    <!-- Super interesting things here!!! -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I tweaked your post to use `<kbd>` for buttons. Obviously feel free to change it back if you don't like it!

Comment: @AdrianLarson I like it! When I first loaded the edit, I wondered what manner of wizardry was at play here. I've never used that tag before.

Comment: Pretty nifty. :)

Comment: Thanks again Derek and Adrian too. I like the fancy buttons